# FCM Push Notification connect to PWA in Flutter Webview

Tags: firebase, flutter, apple-push-notifications, push, progressive-web-apps

So there is possible to send update status push notification from PWA to a device (Android or Ios)?

I have a PWA, and a Flutter based Webview with FCM. (PWA web push work also with FCM)

PWA is Laravel based.